# What does ck.on('pasteState', function() do?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to learn about CKEditor.

I have in my code:

```
ck.on('pasteState', function()
```

Can someone please explain to me what this is doing. I did research on the web but I could not find anything about 'pastestate'.

Thanks

Comment: i guess it is monitoring the paste event on editor.

Comment: Yes I thought this but I would like to find the part of the documentation that describes these events. I cannot find it in the docs at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is an internal event which spread the state of paste event to other plugins. This state is initially calculated in [`clipboard` plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/clipboard/plugin.js#L912-L915) and then other plugins like [pastetext](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/pastetext/plugin.js#L57) and [pasteformword](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/pastefromword/plugin.js#L50) listens on `editor#pasteEvent` to change states of their buttons.